# How do I create text file for Confluence and then import it as a Confluence wiki page?

Tags: wiki, markup, confluence

Here is what I want to accomplish:

1. I am writing a script which will parse some source code, extract some comments that I want it to extract and I will store this text in a text file.
2. I want to write another script that uses the content of this text file to be programatically transformed into a Confluence wiki-page.

Please tell me the best way to do this. I already saw [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DISC/XML-RPC+Page+Updater+Example)

I felt that I could change the input in the above example to take input from text file and update contents of Confluence page. But, I am not sure how it will be formatted. If I have to format it, what do I need to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to XML-RPC you can use the integrated [WebDAV plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/confluence.extra.webdav).

1. Write a script that creates a directory in the selected space.
   The directory name will be the page name. After creating the directory a text-file with the same name (with .txt extension) will be created in the directory which holds the content of the page
2. let your script edit this file in insert the content of your text-file.

Information about the usage of the plugin:

- [Configuring a WebDAV client for Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+a+WebDAV+client+for+Confluence)
- [Confluence WebDAV Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/WBDV/Confluence+WebDAV+Plugin)
- [Troubleshooting WebDAV](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Troubleshooting+WebDAV)

Comment: Thanks! I get what you are saying. But would this not work, given the fact that Confluence has now moved from wiki-markup to a proprietary way of writing content. I mean the markup and formatting might not come up.

Also, what do you think of this:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/127217/import-a-text-file-with-atlassian-cli

Comment: Yes, it is a proprietary way, but the new confluence storage format is XML and most of it is **standard XHTML**. Just the custom elements for macros and more are in custom XML-style. It is very well documented [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+Storage+Format). You can also use Atlassian CLI to create pages, but i am pretty sure that you would again need to use the syntax of the new storage format.

Comment: In addition: You can find a non-official XSD schema for Confluence pages [here](http://www.amnet.net.au/~ghannington/confluence/docs/confluence/s-confluence-xhtml.xsd.html)

Comment: I checked upon  the new format. It will work and I get the new markup style too. Now, the other doubt is whether WebDAV can pull from Confluence or is it capable of pushing content back to Confluence as well? (from the .txt files we're talking about)

Comment: Yes. Any changes you make to the <pagename>.txt file will be immediately be reflected in Confluence.

Comment: Okay, thanks a zillion times!! And the WebDAV plugin is compatible with Confluence 4.3.2 ? It's page says only about Confluence 4.0 and 4.1. Nothing about v4.3.2 [here](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/WBDV/Confluence+WebDAV+Plugin;jsessionid=038DC9CBA077C73FC02104E0997AAA90)

Comment: It is an internal plugin and therefore always compatible with the recent version. The page you r reffering to is not updated frequently. The compatibility is uptodate at the marketplace page (see my first link). Please accept my answer if its the case.

Answer (score 3):

I Also saw the code you are referring to. I tweaked it a bit a produced the following code that me help you for the second part of your question.

My code creates a new space and also a new page from a text file that is inserted in the previously created space.

```
import sys
import xmlrpc.client
import os
import re

# Connects to confluence server with username and password
site_URL = "YOUR_URL"
server = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy(site_URL + "/rpc/xmlrpc")

username = "YOUR_USERNAME"
pwd = "YOUR_PASSWORD" 
token = server.confluence2.login(username, pwd)

# The space you want to add a page to
spacekey = "YOUR_SPACENAME"

# Retrives text from a file
f = open('FileName.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
f.close()

# Creates a new page to insert in the new space from text file content
newpage = {"title":"NEW_PAGENAME", "space":spacekey, "content":content}
server.confluence2.storePage(token, newpage)

server.confluence2.logout(token)
```

For your formatting issues, html is supported, but I have not quite figured out how to use CSS styles other than inline (everthing else does not seem to work).

These styles work when you write them with the HTML macro inside Confluence, but from the remote API, it does not seem to behave the same way.

UPDATE :
You can use the {html} macro to include your html by using :

```
content = server.confluence2.convertWikiToStorageFormat(token, content)
```

You can also specify your CSS in your global CSS stylesheet.
Another option is to develop a plugin to include a CSS resource :
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Creating+a+Stylesheet+Theme

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this way and works petty well for me:

1. I used a Java program to created a programmatic client to create the dynamic content. This created a HTML document out of my plain text.
2. I used a RPC client connected to Confluence to uploaded it as a new page.

Your html will be preserved. But if you want to add CSS or JS/JQuery etc on top of your html you will need to create a Macro and enable it for the Particular page. This feature is not available in Confluence OnDemand.